# Regex to match word that start with "$"

Tags: java, regex

I need match "words" that start with a dollar sign `$`.

I have tried the following regex:

```
\b\$banana\b
```

but this gives the following results:

```
few words have$banana // match, but should not
few words have $banana // not match, but should
```

I can't understand why this happens.

I need to find words so the first case does not have to match, only the second must match. Where am I going wrong?

I use Java for my test, but the regex must work independently from programming language.

Comment: Do you want both to match? What are your expected results?

Comment: I need to find only words this `few words have$banana` does not have to match.

Comment: Then choose Bohemian's answer, or I can also post [`(?<!\\w)[$]banana\\b`](https://regex101.com/r/nB0bI6/2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "not a word boundary" term `\B`:

```
\B\$banana\b
```

Because `$` is *not* a word char, you want to match where the char before the `$` is *also* not word char; this regex won't match `foo$banana`, but will match `foo $banana`.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/vCNYGBXNGl) showing

```
foo $banana bar (match)
foo$banana bar (no match)
foo $bananabar (no match)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))\$banana\b
```

This should do it for you:

https://regex101.com/r/nB0bI6/1

The reason yours is not working is because the first `\b` as there is not a word boundary before `$`.